# Convert timezone value from seconds to W3C hour format

Tags: datetime

Doing an API integration that requires timezones to be handed off in [W3C format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), while Drupal opts to store timezones in seconds.

Wondering what the clean way to do this is, rather than stripping the +/- sign, dividing by 3600 and adding it back on. There has to be a date transformation right?

FYI... W3C looks like this: `-08:00` and Drupal looks like this: `-28800`

Trying to avoid this code...

```
// $val = '-28800';
$sec = substr($val, 1);
$hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
$minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
$w3cTZ = substr($val, 0, 1) .
  str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) .":".
  str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: As this is more of a PHP question, you will probably get better responses on the main SO site.

Comment: It's true. But Drupal provides ways (and the Date module as well) to present/transform the data. May be a PHP thing though yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up this this function...

```
// Convert timezone from second in Drupal to WC3 standard
function timezoneConvert($val, $toSeconds = false) {
  if(!$toSeconds) {
    // Starts like: "-28800" and becomes: "-08:00"
    $sec = substr($val, 1);
    $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
    $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
    $w3cTZ = substr($val, 0, 1) .
      str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) .":".
      str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $w3cTZ;
  }
  else {
    $seconds = 0;
    $units = explode(':',$val,2);
    $seconds += $units[0] * 3600; // Hours
    $seconds += $units[1] * 60; // Minutes
    return $seconds;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, in D7 `$user->timezone` is in this format "America/Los_Angeles" rather than seconds.
Drupal 6 included this info but the column was called `timezone_name`